# API to obtain an access_token in CAM

Tags: cloud-automation-manager

I just attempted to obtain an `access_token` from the latest API and got an `404` error. I used to be able to do this by using a POST on `https://<ip>:30000/cam/v1/auth/camtoken`

Has there been a change in this with the new security model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `camtoken` to `identitytoken`, eg:

`https://<ip>:30000/cam/v1/auth/identitytoken`

In the latest CAM beta code, this token is provided by the IBM Cloud Private platform now.